The command block in the sed command is malfunctioning and cannot be used properly
"I encountered an issue while learning sed commands. Each part of a sed command block must be on a separate line."
such as 123.txt
File contents are as follows
line 1
123
line 2
line 3

I'm using the following command in the Linux terminal:
sed '/123/ {i\good}' 123.txt 

but it shows

sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched '{'.

However, when I use
sed '/123/ { i\
good
}' 123.txt 

it runs correctly. I suspect that sed cannot recognize the backslash \ properly within command blocks.
OS rhel8.8
and
sed (GNU sed) 4.5
I tried running the command in a script, but it still couldn't recognize the newline escape in the command block.
must use as
sed '/123/ { i\
good
}' 123.txt 

The format used in my linux textbook is as follows.
sed '/123/ {i\good}' 123.txt 

I want to know why it can't recognize \. If I write the command without line breaks, how should I write it?"

Perhaps this might help you.

The reason using ChapGPT is banned here for answers is because

while the answers which ChatGPT and other generative AI technologies produce have a high rate of being incorrect, they typically look like the answers might be good and the answers are very easy to produce

Although they may get better in future, for now I suggest only using them in areas where you already have a good idea of what valid answers look like.

You have various options to specify your sed script.
use actual newlines
For maximum portability (and readability, which becomes more important for longer scripts), use actual newlines, as in your working code:
sed '/123/ { i\
good
}' 123.txt 

(sed does accept semi-colons as an alternative to newlines in some situations but that does not help here.)
use multiple -e
The POSIX specification for sed states that multiple -e options can be given, where each after the first are treated as if being preceded by a newline:
sed -e '123/ { i\' -e 'good' -e '}' 123.txt

This works with many sed implementations. Unfortunately not all follow POSIX (e.g. some BSD will fail).
insert newlines using the shell
Assuming one has a variable (say nl) that contains a newline, it can be used as:
sed '123/ { i\'"$nl"'good'"$nl"'}' 123.txt

Note that the variable use is in double-quotes.
How to get the newline into the variable?

You could just do:

nl='
'

but then you might as well just write the sed command with actual newlines.

Some shells provide non-standard $'...' expansion:

nl=$'\n'

(Or just use directly.)

If IFS has its default value, its third character is a newline but relying on that is a bad idea.

Some versions of printf (e.g. bash) allow storing a string directly into a variable:


printf -v nl '\n'


Standard printf can generate newlines. Unfortunately, an invocation like nl=$(printf '\n') fails because the shell discards trailing newlines on $(...) output! So some trickery is needed. For example:

nlx=$(printf '\nx')
nl=${nlx%?}

or
eval "$(printf 'nl="\n"')"


there's also the somewhat unreadable sed "$(printf '%s\n' '/123/ { i\' 'good' '}')" 123.txt

nl is also a command so this was not the best choice for variable name

sed recognizes the \ just fine, it's simply an escape character for the character that follows it. In the working script the \ is escaping a newline before the string you want to insert. In the failing script the \ is escaping the g at the start of good, the word you want to insert. Those are 2 very different things.
To portably do what you want with sed you must use the multi-line version but you can just use awk instead whether single or multi-line:
$ seq 3 | awk '/2/ {print "good"} 1'
1
good
2
3


$ seq 3 | awk '/2/ {
    print "good"
} 1'
1
good
2
3


$ seq 3 | awk '1; /2/ {print "good"}'
1
2
good
3


$ seq 3 | awk '1; /2/ {
    print "good"
}'
1
2
good
3

P.S. If you really wanted to do that with sed, then using GNU sed you could do:
$ seq 3 | sed '/2/i good'
1
good
2
3


$ seq 3 | sed '/2/a good'
1
2
good
3

but that's not portable to other sed variants:
$ seq 3 | sed --posix '/2/i good'
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: expected \ after `a', `c' or `i'


I know I can use the awk command for processing, but the requirement to have each part of a sed command block on a separate line confuses me."

@the_stars_wy it's just the POSIX-defined syntax for sed to insert a block of text, think of it as being similar to a here-document in shell, if that helps.

So, the sed command format provided by ChatGPT is incorrect.

@the_stars_wy I'd expect so, ChatGPT is wrong over 60% of the time in answers to software questions. My personal experience is it's wrong over 90% of the time for questions about shell or other Unix tools - it almost always gives an answer that's non-portable, inefficient, fragile, etc. I don't know if that's because the domain is difficult or just that I know what the correct answers should be. That's what happens when a tool learns by reading Internet posts!

Because this error appeared in my Linux textbook, which was authored by my professor, I have always thought it was my mistake.

Linux != UNIX. The tools in Linux are often GNU tools which (at least a recent version of) do support the single-line version you're using, but that doesn't mean it'll work in other UNIX-like environments that aren't Linux, e.g. MacOS which uses BSD rather than GNU tools by default, nor that they'll work on a Linux system that has non-GNU versions of the tools installed. Get a POSIX text book, not a Linux one, if you want to learn how to write code that's portable across UNIX-like platforms.

I think the first statement re backslashes may not be quite right. posix talks about Other <backslash> characters in text  but text specifically refers to the argument of some commands. backslash doesn't generally escape the following character. in particular, I think the backslash after i is part of the actual function syntax - if the following character is not newline, result varies between implementations
